# What does ~/ mean before a directory's name in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

For example, what would it mean to say:

> cd ~/mydirectory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`~` is a shortcut for the home directory, so

```
cd ~/mydirectory
```

Will move to `mydirectory` if there is such a directory in your home folder, otherwise it will throw a directory does not exist error.

Example:

[image]

Your home directory is located at `/home/<username>`.

Trivia: This is why the default bash prompt has a tilde in it like this `user@host:~$`. The tilde indicates that you are currently in your home directory. If you move somewhere else, for example into `/etc` it will show `user@host:/etc$`.

Comment: I've always used `$HOME` instead, for clarity and because some programs don't expand a tilde.

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for your home directory. For example, my desktop directory is at

```
 /home/marc/Desktop
```

or

```
 ~/Desktop
```

for short.